# How to avoid multiple else conditions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a snippet to check if a user is logged in and the token is valid.
If this is not the case, the user should get redirected to the login page.

But with my attempt I have to use multiple `else` lines which are doing the same thing: redirecting...

Is it possible to do this a bit smarter avoiding multiple `else`. I think with that done, the code gets smaller...

```
static async getInitialProps (context, apolloClient) {
  const { req } = context
  const initProps = {}
  if (req && req.headers) {
    const cookies = req.headers.cookie
    if (cookies && typeof cookies === 'string') {
      const cookiesJSON = jsHttpCookie.parse(cookies)
      initProps.token = cookiesJSON['auth-token']
      if (cookiesJSON['auth-token']) {
        jwt.verify(cookiesJSON['auth-token'], secret, (error, decoded) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error(error)
            redirect(context, '/login')
          }
          if (decoded) initProps.id = decoded.id
        })
      } else {
        redirect(context, '/login')
      }
    } else {
      redirect(context, '/login')
    }
  } else {
    redirect(context, '/login')
  }
  return initProps
}
```

Comment: Why not write one condition `if(something&&somethingelse&&other)` so you can use one `}else{` to `redirect(context, '/login')`

Comment: You could always return early to avoid some of the nesting, e.g. `if (!( req && req.headers) ) { return initProps }`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: introduce a bool like isValid set to false. When reaching the correct branch, set it to true. Then at the end a simple if(isValid) .. ... else redirect

Comment: It is kind of Christmas tree, clean your code and use broadcast event emitter, promises and or early return